# Correct Permutations Code give wrong answer in specials case

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, logic, permutation

[Link to Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjT0m.png)
For this question, I wrote this code -

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def permuteUnique(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        nums.sort()
        ans = []

        def backtrack(index, nums):
            if index == len(nums):
                ans.append(nums.copy())
                return 
            
            for i in range(index, len(nums)):
                if i > index and nums[i] == nums[i-1]:  # checking for duplicate values
                    continue
                nums[index], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[index]
                backtrack(index + 1, nums)
                nums[index], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[index]

        backtrack(0, nums)
        return ans
```

It's working fine for given test cases but not for all. I know something is wrong. But what, specifically code line

```
if i > index and nums[i] == nums[i-1]:  # checking for duplicate values
                    continue
```

why these lines are not avoiding duplicate permutations, it's working in combinations but not in permutations.

Comment: Do not tag this question as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code swaps `nums[index]` with `nums[i]`, so the check for duplicate values should be

```
if i > index and nums[i] == nums[index]:  # checking for duplicate values
                    continue
```